# Python: Emulate Excel´s Index-Match with info in 2 columns of df1 to be used to find position in df2

Tags: python, indexing, match, vlookup

Among others, I´m trying to handle large data sets which is why I switched from Excel to Python. I managed to solve most problems, however, the following seems to complex for my apparently bad google skills.

Available data:
I have a pandas dataframe1 with 500 k rows. Each row contains a time stamp, a machine number, and an indicator if it is active or not. 
I have another pandas dataframe2 with ~30 million rows (One per second in a year) and 60 columns (1 per each machine).

Objective: I´d like to fill the empty matrix of df2 by looking at each row in df1. In df1 I want to use the timestamp info to find the according row in df2, and in df1 I want to use the machine number to find the according column in df2, then paste the value in df2

> ```
> import pandas as pd
>
> df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':[1, 1, 4, 5],
>                  'machine_number':[123, 789, 789, 123],
>                  'active_inactive':[1, 0, 1, 0]})    
> df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'time':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
>                  '123':['', '', '', '', ''],
>                  '789':['', '', '', '', '']})
> ```

After the index match emulation I am aiming for the following result

> ```
> df_3 = pd.DataFrame({'time':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
>                  '123':[1, '', '', '', 0],
>                  '789':[0, '', '', 1, '']})
> ```

Eventually I want to populate the empty values with the latest active/inactive indicator until a new indicator appears:

> ```
> df_4 = pd.DataFrame({'time':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
>                  '123':[1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
>                  '789':[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]})
> ```

But that´s probably a problem for another day that I can try to solve on my own.

Thanks in advance for any helpful info.

Best
Sven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.  So this question is actually a bit more complicated than it might seem.  The first thing to understand is that pandas works best with "tidy" data (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data).  Where as excel is great for data input it's not optimized for analysis (as you've figured out).  You'll learn more about this as you get more into coding with dataframes, but for now just understand that things need to be in different formats to work properly.

So, first you need to take your second datafame from wide to long format (you need to tidy it):

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':[1, 1, 4, 5],
                 'machine_number':[123, 789, 789, 123],
                 'active_inactive':[1, 0, 1, 0]})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], # note that I changed this name to 'timestamp' so
                                                  # it's the same in both dataframe
                 '123':['', '', '', '', ''],
                 '789':['', '', '', '', '']})

(df_2_melted = pd.melt(df_2, id_vars=['timestamp'], 
                             value_vars=['123', '789'], 
                             var_name='machine_number')
                 .drop(columns='value'))

df_2_melted['machine_number'] = df_2_melted['machine_number'].astype('int64')
# I had to change this column to 'int64' because the next operation won't work unless the
# columns are the same type
```

That get's you this:

```
    timestamp   machine_number
0   1           123
1   2           123
2   3           123
3   4           123
4   5           123
5   1           789
6   2           789
7   3           789
8   4           789
9   5           789
```

You can then 'merge' the columns together.  This is like a join operation from sql or and `index_match`/`vlookup` in excel:

```
merged = pd.merge(df_2_melted, df_1, how='left', on=['timestamp', 'machine_number'])

merged

    timestamp   machine_number  active_inactive
0   1           123             1.0
1   2           123             NaN
2   3           123             NaN
3   4           123             NaN
4   5           123             0.0
5   1           789             0.0
6   2           789             NaN
7   3           789             NaN
8   4           789             1.0
9   5           789             NaN
```

Then, if you want to get it back to the same format as in the original dataframe, you need to `pivot` it back out (as the name suggests, this is like a pivot table from excel):

```
merged.pivot(index='timestamp', columns='machine_number', values='active_inactive').reset_index(drop=True)

machine_number  123     789
0               1.0     0.0
1               NaN     NaN
2               NaN     NaN
3               NaN     1.0
4               0.0     NaN
```

That being said, you're going to want to keep everything in the tidy format for your analysis so I'd only suggest pivoting if you want to eventually write it out as a spreadsheet to give to someone else.

Comment: Hi Ben, that solved exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated, especially the additional background info regarding Python/data management

Comment: I did, but I guess I´m too much of a newbie yet ;) ("Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.")

Comment: Right, well stick at it.  I made the full-time switch from excel to R (and now python) a few years back and it's sooo much better.